# Parse NSString using CHCSVParser returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsstring

I am trying to parse an NSString using CHCSVParser, I have downloaded the sample project from github here

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

And have had a look through the project and specifically at the UnitTests.m file which shows an example of how to read a .csv file or from a csv NSString.

I have used these lines of code to try and parse my NSString

```
//file = myNSString of comma seperated values
    NSStringEncoding encoding = 0;
    NSString *csv = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file usedEncoding:&encoding error:nil];
    NSArray *fields = [csv CSVComponents];
    NSLog(@"fields: %@", fields);
```

This is what the NSString "file" looks like that I am trying to parse:

```
"Completed Item","Un-complete Item","Damaged Item"
```

When I pass it through that code the fields Array returns nothing. It looks like this:

```
fields: (null)
```

And yes, the file contains the string I have added above.

Comment: Did you check to see if `csv` is `nil` or not?

Comment: yea, it is nil.. so thats where something is going wrong. I have been reading trying to figure this out but so many different sources lots to get through

Comment: the only difference that instead of reading from a file to a NSString where the NSString is then used I just have a NSString that I am trying to use. this is the missing line that I am not suing as I dont need to read the NSString from a file. **NSString *file = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"csv"];**

Comment: If you already have a string then why are you trying to read it from a file? Is `file` the string variable with the comma separated values? Just do `NSArray *fields = [file CSVComponents];`.

Comment: ahh.. I thought stringWithContentsOfFile was a delegate method of CHCSVParser class slight oversight there.. what a pain. thanks for the help

Comment: How could that method be a delegate? You don't even have a parser, you've set no delegate, and it's obviously a standard method on the `NSString` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a string with your comma separated values. You can't use that string to load a file with the same name. Just do:

```
NSString *file = @"Completed Item","Un-complete Item","Damaged Item";
NSArray *fields = [file CSVComponents];
NSLog(@"fields: %@", fields);
```

Comment: okay so I just got back from trying this and I have yet to research it yet but this dosnt work... the array only returns one field that looks like this when i log it in the debugger. **fields: (
    "\"Completed Item\"",
    "\"Un-complete Item\"",
    "\"Damaged Item\""
)**

Comment: What do you get for `fields.count`?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an array of an array which contains 3 strings?

Comment: I have it.. have updated my question with the answer.

Comment: So I was right, you got an array of an array. This makes sense. The top level array has a value for each line in the string. Each sub-array is the fields for the given line.

Comment: sorry I was doing more debugging to double check results!! lol just making sure everything was in order. you have your upvote and tick! and I even thanked you in my question update haha!! cheers dude..

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author.)*

This is how I achieved it in the end.

```
NSString *firstJSONString = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *fields = [firstJSONString CSVComponents]; // for some reason returns 1 object .. not sure why
NSArray *seperatedArrayOfFields = [fields objectAtIndex:0]; // this line splits fields into 3 NSString objects
```